# Enable location services in Android without any dialog

Tags: android

I want to enable/disable location services for my app but not have to prompt the user to enable it if it's turned off. All the examples I have seen require some dialog to be shown. This seems kind of senseless given that the user has already granted permission to use location services.

Comment: Which dialog are you referring to? The permission dialog that is shown on OS's running Marshmallow+?

Comment: you/your app does not have permission to do this, just because a user has given access does not mean they cant revoke that access at a later point in time

Comment: But the user might not want to enable it _now_.  From what I've seen, location services use more battery, and possibly mobile data, and the user may be low on either/both.

Comment: @SlashG Even if you granted permission to use location services, you will be prompted to enable the service if it's turned off. I am looking for a way to avoid this prompt and just enable the location service when I want to.

Comment: @TripeHound That's a valid point but it if the app needs control of the location service and the user is made fully aware that the app needs to turn it on/off when it is running, this should be acceptable as well, without requiring some dialog to prompt the user with.

Comment: @tyczj No prompt should be necessary if the permission has been granted.

Comment: This is not the best way forward, but if not using the permission dialog is so important to you, you could target a lower version (22, maybe). That way, your app's permissions will be taken from the user at install-time and not at run-time. I repeat, **this is not a good way forward**.

Comment: @SlashG: AFAIK, the OP is not referring to having permission to access locations. Instead, the OP is referring to the ability to enable location providers, even if the user has them disabled. Those are separate things.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for the correction! I was thrown off by the mention of dialogs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to enable/disable location services for my app but not have to prompt the user to enable it if it's turned off.

Fortunately, that is not possible on ordinary devices, for obvious privacy reasons, barring some bug in Android (or specific device models). System apps might be able to do this, and this should be possible on rooted devices, though I do not have the details for either scenario.

> This seems kind of senseless given that the user has already granted permission to use location services.

Prior to Android 6.0, users did not have the ability on ordinary Android devices to control permissions individually. As a result, they might disable location services, just to be able to use apps that happen to request locations.

Even on Android 6.0+, just because the user granted your app permission to use locations does not mean that the user wants location data to be available all the time. They might only want locations to be available to apps at certain times (e.g., while travelling and needing location-related information more). Or, as a commenter noted, the user might keep locations disabled for power reasons, more so than privacy.

> if the app needs control of the location service and the user is made fully aware that the app needs to turn it on/off when it is running

That would need to be a separate capability with a separate permission (e.g., some `MANAGE_LOCATION_PROVIDERS` permission), or possibly be part of the device admin/device owner APIs. You are certainly welcome to file a feature request for this.

> No prompt should be necessary if the permission has been granted

Permissions to access location data do *not* imply permission to override the user's enabled/disabled setting for location providers. If it did, there would be no point in having location providers be able to be disabled.